# Is Quickfix line -> message.getHeader().getField(msgType); redundant?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

IN the quickfix J source what is the point of this line of code

```
 message.getHeader().getField(msgType);
```

in

```
 public void crack42(Message message, SessionID sessionID)
        throws UnsupportedMessageType, FieldNotFound, IncorrectTagValue {
        MsgType msgType = new MsgType();
        message.getHeader().getField(msgType);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`message.getField(x)` will only look at the fields in the message *body*, not in the header or trailer.  So in your example, `message.getField(msgType)` would raise a `FieldNotFound` exception, because MsgType (field 35) is a header field and not in the body.

To get the MessageType, you need to look in the header, hence `message.getHeader().getField(msgType)`.

Comment: seems like a strange way of doing it, I would have preferred a assignment rather than a pass by reference modification

Comment: Remember that QuickFIX/J started as direct port of the C++ engine. In that context, the MsgType was probably allocated on the stack and passed by reference to the getField method.

Comment: Java might offer a return-value version of the method also.  Check the API.  You'll still have to call it on the header for header fields, though.